# hex-like NSString to int value

Tags: ios, type-conversion

How can I conver it into 192 as integer value?

```
NSString* hex = @"c0";
```

Or I have `char a1 = **'\xc0';`** How do I convert it into `int`? I cant use atoi in Xcode. :(

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You have two choices, a C style one and an Objective-C one, first one is something like

```
long value = 0;
sscanf_s([hex cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding], "%x", &value);
```

Latter is something like

```
long value = 0;
NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:hex];
[scanner scanHexInt:&value];
```

Comment: I recently started developing for a Bluetooth device and couldn't figure out how to properly pass the string representation of my hex values.  Haven't heard of the NSScanner class until now, so thank you! This is the answer, it works as intended.